# Como faço para acessar uma porta serial de um servidor remoto por SSH com PHP?

Tags: php, socket, ssh, serial, porta-serial

Encontrei sobre conexões por SSH e por socket a servidores remotos e também sobre conexões a portas seriais locais, mas ainda não encontrei sobre como juntar as  coisas.

Cenário: Preciso acessar a porta /dev/ttyACM0 de um modem TX (o qual conecto via SSH) p/ enviar os comandos.

OBS.: Testei em um terminal bash ubuntu e funcionou normalmente, porém no terminal picocom do modem não funcionou.

Segue o trecho do script PHP que estou usando até o momento:

```
<?php
 //(...) // definição das variáveis,etc.

 $connection = ssh2_connect($server, $port);
 if (ssh2_auth_password($connection, $username, $password)) {

 // aqui coloco o comando que envio p/ o modem
 $cmd = 'network command '. $param1 .' svlan '. $param2 . ' ' . $param3; 

 $stream = ssh2_exec($connection, $cmd); // Executa o comando
 $errorStream = ssh2_fetch_stream($stream, SSH2_STREAM_STDERR);

 // Habilita streams bloqueantes
 stream_set_blocking($errorStream, true);
 stream_set_blocking($stream, true);

 // Saída
 echo "Output: " . stream_get_contents($stream);
 echo "<br><br>Error: " . stream_get_contents($errorStream);

 // Fecha streams
 fclose($errorStream);
 fclose($stream);
}
 else
{
   die('Authentication Failed...');
}

?>
```

Comment: Já tentou com [esse tutorial/exemplos?](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.ssh2-connect.php)

Comment: Já sim...obrigado... Na verdade estou testando alguns comandos aqui... Em um terminal linux bash com SSH em si já consegui executar com os comandos ssh2_connect e ssh2_exec, porém não estou conseguindo comunicar com a porta serial do modem remoto citado... Não sei ainda se o problema é com o terminal do modem que é diferente... ou se é problema com o socket...

Comment: Autalizei a pergunta e inclui o código que estou usando p/ facilitar a descrição/entendimento...